# Getting Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0 in JTable row deletion

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

I have written code to make a swing application with JDBC connectivity. The rows are entered into the table from the side panel which contains some fields. These fields are entered into the database and then they are displayed on the JTable. I have added insertion, updating and deletion logic also. Insertion and updating the row are working fine. But when I try to delete the row, I am getting the exception.

TablePanel.java:

```
    package jdbc;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

import com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.Table;

public class TablePanel extends JPanel {
    JTable jTable;
    DefaultTableModel dtm = null;
    String[] columns = { "Sno", "Sname", "Batch", "Trainer", "Score", "Update", "Delete" };
    Object[][] rows = null;
    JScrollPane jp;
    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    static SidePanel sp;
    public TablePanel() throws SQLException {
        super();
        dtm = new DefaultTableModel(rows, columns);
        this.jTable = new JTable(dtm);

        Dimension dim = new Dimension(600, 1000);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.jp = new JScrollPane(jTable);
        add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jTable.getColumn("Update").setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
        jTable.getColumn("Update").setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor(new JTextField("Update")));
        jTable.getColumn("Delete").setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
        jTable.getColumn("Delete").setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor(new JTextField("Delete")));
        jp.setSize(600, 600);
        con = ConnectionObj.getConnection();
        displayTable();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void displayTable() throws SQLException {
        dtm.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
        dtm.fireTableDataChanged();
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT * FROM student";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        String arr[] = new String[7];
        int flag =0;
        while(rs.next()){
        //  System.out.println(rs.getString(i)+"hello\n");
            for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
            {arr[i-1] = rs.getString(i);
            flag++;
            }if(flag == 5){
                arr[5] = "Update";
                arr[6] = "Delete";
                dtm.addRow(arr);
                flag=0;
                }
        }


    }

    public void insertRow(Object[] arr) throws SQLException
    {

        String sql,select_sql;
        select_sql = "SELECT sno FROM student where sno = ?";
        PreparedStatement psmt1 = con.prepareStatement(select_sql);
        psmt1.setString(1, (String)arr[0]);
        ResultSet rs1 = psmt1.executeQuery();
        if(rs1.next()){
            System.out.println(rs1.getString(1));
            updateRow(arr);
        }
        else{
        sql = "Insert into student values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";
        PreparedStatement psmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        psmt.setString(1, (String)arr[0]);
        psmt.setString(2, (String)arr[1]);
        psmt.setString(3, (String)arr[2]);
        psmt.setString(4, (String)arr[3]);
        psmt.setString(5, (String)arr[4]);
        psmt.execute();
        }
        sp.clearText();
        displayTable();
    }
    public void setSidePanel(SidePanel sp){
        this.sp = sp;
    }
    public void updateRow(Object arr[]) throws SQLException{
//      int num = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
        String str = (String)arr[0];
        System.out.println(str+" hi ");
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "UPDATE student SET sno=?, sname = ?,batch = ?,trainer = ?,score = ? where sno = ?";
        PreparedStatement psmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        psmt.setString(1, (String)arr[0]);
        psmt.setString(2, (String)arr[1]);
        psmt.setString(3, (String)arr[2]);
        psmt.setString(4, (String)arr[3]);
        psmt.setString(5, (String)arr[4]);
        psmt.setString(6, str);
        psmt.execute();
//      displayTable();
    }

    public void deleteRow(int rows2) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("in delete");
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql;
        int count=0;
        String id = null;
        sql = "SELECT * FROM student";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            if(count==rows2)
                {
                 id = rs.getString(1);

                break;
                }
            count++;    
        }

        String sql2="Delete from student where sno='"+id+"'";
        stmt.execute(sql2);
        displayTable();

    }

}

class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer {

    public ButtonRenderer() {

        setOpaque(true);

    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,

            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
        this.add( new JTextField( value.toString()  ) );
        this.add( new JButton("Update"));
        this.add( new JButton("Delete"));
        return this;

    }
}

class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
{
  protected JButton btn;
   private String lbl;
   private Boolean clicked=false;
   public TablePanel tp;
   int rows ;
private boolean clicked2=false;
   public ButtonEditor(JTextField txt) {
    super(txt);

    btn=new JButton();
    btn.setOpaque(true);

    //WHEN BUTTON IS CLICKED
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        fireEditingStopped();
      }
    });
  }

   //OVERRIDE A COUPLE OF METHODS
   @Override
  public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object obj,
      boolean selected, int row, int col) {

      //SET TEXT TO BUTTON,SET CLICKED TO TRUE,THEN RETURN THE BTN OBJECT
     lbl=(obj==null) ? "":obj.toString();
     btn.setText(lbl);
     if(lbl.equals("Update"))
     clicked=true;
     else
         clicked2=true;
     rows = row;
     System.out.println(row+" "+col);
    return btn;
  }

  //IF BUTTON CELL VALUE CHNAGES,IF CLICKED THAT IS
   @Override
  public Object getCellEditorValue() {

     if(clicked)
      {
      //SHOW US SOME MESSAGE
       try {
           System.out.println("update");
        TablePanel.sp.updatetextPanel(rows);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      }

     if(clicked2)
     {
         try {
             System.out.println("helll");
            TablePanel.sp.deleteRowPanel(rows);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
    //SET IT TO FALSE NOW THAT ITS CLICKED
    clicked=false;
    clicked2=false;
    return new String(lbl);
  }

   @Override
  public boolean stopCellEditing() {

         //SET CLICKED TO FALSE FIRST
      clicked=false;
    return super.stopCellEditing();
  }

   @Override
  protected void fireEditingStopped() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.fireEditingStopped();
  }

   public void setTable(TablePanel tp){
       this.tp = tp;
   }
}
```

This is the logic I have written. In this, I am using SidePanel class which calls deleteRow() method. I am getting an error as below:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setValueAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.editingStopped(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.fireEditingStopped(Unknown Source)
at jdbc.ButtonEditor.fireEditingStopped(TablePanel.java:266)
at jdbc.ButtonEditor$1$1.run(TablePanel.java:198)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How to rectify this error? What is the mistake I have done? I am unable to understand what is the error here? Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No, It is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I delete JTable row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612014/why-am-i-getting-an-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-when-i-delete-jtable-row)

Comment: But that didn't help @Alien, The problem still persists.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).